# Entity Framework, eager loading and big object graph

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a WPF project that works on a local database with projects. The local databased is later synced with a server.
Each project have multiple systems, and each of these have multiple "tags". The tag have a product, and the product consist of multiple materials in an pretty advanced structure. A simple structure would be like this:

- Project

  - Systems

    - Tags

      - Products

        - Material 1
        - Material 2
        - Material 3
      - Tag requirements
    - System requirements

I have two problems I have to solve right now.

1. When the project loads I need to load the whole project from database and work with a local copy until the user saves it. When I try eager loading it will take forever and I found out thay you should not have to many includes since it bad for performance. 
   Is there a good practice how I should load a deep structure into memory?
2. The reason I need to load it into memory is so the user can work on a copy and then at a given point can save it to the database. I have multiple calculation function that depends on different part of the tree. My conclusions have let me thinking I need to post the whole project (or at least a system) to the business layer since all data can be edited local (memory)

Am I thinking this the wrong way? Maybe there is a way to load the whole database (since it isn't that big and it's already local) into a memorydb and have a local context in entity framework. And when the user saves, I save it to the real database and then get synced.

As you hear I am not sure how to solve this so any tips are welcome

Comment: how big is the object graph, how many rows total?

Comment: I'm not sure of final version but I have about 20 diffrent classes that can be changed by user (or calculation) right now, and there is "many" more to come. Some of these have navigation property to let's say Material that have values not changable for the user.

edit: forgot number of rows. Total is "hard" to tell since the user can add calculation values for diffrent conditions, and this can be as many as 50. So some of the classes exists in 50 versions (only calculated)

Answer (score 1):

When using .Include with N:M relationships, Entity Framework performs a left outer join, returning potentially far more rows than actually needed.

There is a technique to more precisely load the object graph.  It is a lot of coding and pretty ugly, but can provide far better performance.  The technique is described in detail (with example) [in this blog](https://anthymecaillard.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/ef-improve-your-objects-graph-loading/).

> My technique is to query once per levels and then link the objects in your application.
>
> This technique is automatic (lazy) in others ORM like NHibernate as the “batch loading” but in EntityFramework you have to do it manualy.

Comment: Hi! looks like the link is broken... could you share your solution here or fix the link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you, the way I resolved the issue with a ton of Include statements is breaking them into small groups.

Instead of this:

```
scarRevision = db.ScarRevisions
.Include(s => s.Author)
.Include(s => s.Scar.Author)
.Include(s => s.Scar.LockedBy)
.Include(s => s.Scar.Part)
.Include(s => s.Scar.Supplier)
.Include(s => s.ScarGeneralSection.GeneralSectionAttachments)
.Include(s => s.ScarGeneralSection.SupplierContacts.Select(sc => sc.Contact))
// on and on and on...
.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Scar.ScarNumber == scarNumber && s.RevisionNumber == revisionNumber);
```

I use this:

```
scarRevision = db.ScarRevisions
.Include(s => s.Author)
.Include(s => s.Scar.Author)
.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Scar.ScarNumber == scarNumber && s.RevisionNumber == revisionNumber);

scarRevision = db.ScarRevisions
.Include(s => s.Scar.LockedBy)
.Include(s => s.Scar.Part)
.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Scar.ScarNumber == scarNumber && s.RevisionNumber == revisionNumber);

scarRevision = db.ScarRevisions
.Include(s => s.Scar.Supplier)
.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Scar.ScarNumber == scarNumber && s.RevisionNumber == revisionNumber);
```

It reduced my query from taking nearly 20 seconds to just 3. Still a little bit too much, but nearly 10 times better then before.